# Impossible to Install PG gem on my mac with Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install the pg gem in order to work again with my rails projects. But I get this error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing pg:    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for pg_config... no No pg_config... trying anyway. If
> ```
>
> building fails, please try again with 
>   --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config checking for libpq-fe.h... no Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
>     --with-pg   --without-pg    --with-pg-config    --without-pg-config
>     --with-pg_config    --without-pg_config     --with-pg-dir
>     --without-pg-dir    --with-pg-include
>     --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include  --with-pg-lib
>     --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.0
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/gem_make.out

I tried everything I found on stackoverflow but I still get this error.

If I try to install postgresql using brew I get the following waring:

> Warning: postgresql-9.2.4 already installed, it's just not linked

If I try to link

> brew link postgresql Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4...
>   Warning: Could not link postgresql. Unlinking...
>
> Error: Could not symlink file:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/share/man/man7/WITH.7
>   /usr/local/share/man/man7 is not writable. You should change its
>   permissions.

Help Please

NOTE: I already installed the command line tools for mavericks.

---

If I uninstall using homebrew and try to install again, I get this error:

> ==> Downloading http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.2.4/postgresql-9.2.4.tar.bz2
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%
>
> ==> Patching patching file src/pl/plpython/Makefile patching file contrib/uuid-ossp/uuid-ossp.c
>   ==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4 --datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/share/postgresql --docdir=/usr/local/Cellar/p
>   ==> make install-world
>   ==> Caveats
>
> ## Build Notes
>
> If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x
>   installed, you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
>   https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/issue/2510
>
> ## Create/Upgrade a Database
>
> If this is your first install, create a database with:   initdb
>   /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
>
> To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.2) of
>   PostgreSQL, see:
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/upgrading.html
>
> ## Loading Extensions
>
> By default, Homebrew builds all available Contrib extensions. To see a
>   list of all available extensions, from the psql command line, run:
>   SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;
>
> To load any of the extension names, navigate to the desired database
>   and run:   CREATE EXTENSION [extension name];
>
> For instance, to load the tablefunc extension in the current database,
>   run:   CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
>
> For more information on the CREATE EXTENSION command, see:
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createextension.html For
>   more information on extensions, see:
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/contrib.html
>
> ## Other
>
> Some machines may require provisioning of shared memory:
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC
>   When installing the postgres gem, including ARCHFLAGS is recommended: 
>   ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
>
> To install gems without sudo, see the Homebrew wiki.
>
> To have launchd start postgresql at login:
>       ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents Then to load postgresql now:
>       launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist Or, if you don't
>   want/need launchctl, you can just run:
>       pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start Warning: Could not link
>   postgresql. Unlinking... Error: The `brew link` step did not complete
>   successfully The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
>   You can try again using `brew link postgresql'
>   ==> Summary   /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4: 2831 files, 38M, built in 4.9 minutes

---

SOLUTION:

I execute this command in order to change the permission of the folder:

> sudo chown jeanosorio /usr/local/share/man/man7

Then

> brew link postgresql Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.1... 421
>   symlinks created

And finally:

> sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
>
> Fetching: pg-0.17.0.gem (100%) Building native extensions.  This could
>   take a while... Successfully installed pg-0.17.0

Answer (score 267, accepted):

If you want to avoid using MacPorts, you can download the [Postgres App](http://postgresapp.com) and place it into the Application directory.

Then, specify the location of newly downloaded `pg_config`:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config
```

If you run in to missing headers problem, try specifying the `include` directory of the app:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-include='/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/include/'
```

Comment: Just a note that you can still use bundler by setting a config env variable: `export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config"`

Comment: If you are using Postgres 9.3 (latest as of today), you can do this:

```gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config```

Comment: Using Postgres93.app worked but had to add the bin path to PATH env variable to bundle install.

Comment: Had to get this working using 

`gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications//Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config`

Comment: Thanks! i was getting 

    Warning: Could not link postgresql. Unlinking...
    Error: Could not symlink file:... is not writable. You should change its permissions.

And everything is brew fault,after i brew install/link postgresql

The installation goes to:
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4... 

which is in my case a VERY CONFLICTIVE FOLDER, downloading pg and gem install using it solve the problem THANKS!!!!!!

Comment: I had to do this: `sudo su` and `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config`

Comment: Just a quick note, as the `pg` versions increment, so will this command as it's looking within a specific folder in the app's contents. The default version of `pg` at the time of writing this is `9.4`, so beware. You'll see the same errors on `gem install` as you did before because you're not providing it with header files.

Comment: I work with multiple ruby versions, so I found it inconvenient to always add the `--with-pg-config` option at the end (and I would like it to work with the `bundle` command).

I found that adding a symlink works well.

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config /usr/local/bin`

Comment: If you go down the Postgres App route, I'd also suggest to update your PATH to include all the pg commands such as dumpdb. To update your path: sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp

Comment: There should be an easier way to do this after all these years

Comment: ```export CONFIGURE_ARGS=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config```

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me on OSX Catalina 10.15.6,  gem  pg:1.2.3 with PostgreSQL 12 installed.

Answer (score 78):

Use brew to get `postgresql`

```
brew install postgresql
```

Check you have pg_config in the installed brew. I found mine in

> /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/bin/pg_config

Check via :

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/bin/pg_config
> /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/bin/pg_config
```

Once done, install the `pg` gem with

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: worked for me after trying to many different things. i just had to make sure to use the correct version number (9.3.5_1 in my case)!

Comment: Use `ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.*/bin/pg_config` to find the real path and combined `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=$(ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.*/bin/pg_config)`

Comment: A bit more detailed description about what happens here https://deveiate.org/code/pg/README-OS_X_rdoc.html

Answer (score 37):

I wasn't able to install postgres via MacPorts. Instead, I installed [Postgress.app](http://postgresapp.com/). and called

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

*Note: in newer versions (in 9.3 at least) the path is actually:* `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config`

Comment: This works, but note that sometimes Postgres.app is installed as Postgres<NN>.app where NN is the version number.

Answer (score 12):

If you have homebrew, just type:

> $ brew install postgresql

Comment: This worked for me - I had PostgreSQL already installed, but I guess I had to install it again, to refresh the headers(?) Then I could do `gem install pg`

Answer (score 11):

For me, on Yosemite, I didn't need to specify `pg_config` path. The following got it done.

```
brew install postgresql
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

Seems like architecture flag is the key.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another alternative in case you want to use the postgresql installer directly. There's a couple of hoops you gotta jump through to begin with after updating to mavericks. Here's what I did:

Install the xcode command line tools first:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Download and install the latest version of PostgreSQL (9.3.1), in my case I just used the graphical installer. Here's the link to the downloads page:

```
http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx
```

Just choose all of the defaults it gives you. It my case it installed postgres to the following directory, if you installed it to a different directory, just remember the path you chose, because you'll need it shortly.

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3
```

If you now try and install the latest pg gem (0.17.0) you'll need to pass a couple of options on the command line. This is what I used:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config
```

If you installed postgres to a different location then you'll need to fix up the path to the pg_config file.

If it complains of a missing 'libpq.5.dylib' file while trying install the pg gem you'll need to create a symlink pointing to the actual location of this file. Postgres is looking for it in your /usr/local/lib/ directory so create a symlink in there and redirect it to its actual location. In my case I had to run:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Once you've done that, retry installing the gem again and hopefully it will work for you the same way it did for me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case (i needed PG 0.16.0 on Mavericks), i installed postgresql via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)

```
sudo port install postgresql90
```

and then

```
gem install pg -v '0.16.0' -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/pg_config
```

For the latest version you need to deduct -v '0.16.0'

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/pg_config
```

If you have Homebrew installed do not install MacPorts before you [read about their coexistense](https://superuser.com/questions/181337/is-it-safe-to-install-both-homebrew-and-macports-on-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 5):

Place the missing `--with-pg-config` in Bundler's config file: `/Users/<your_user>/.bundle/config` to make your life easier.

```
---
BUNDLE_BUILD__PG: --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
BUNDLE_BUILD__EXAMPLE_GEM: --other-configs
BUNDLE_BUILD__OTHER_EXAMPLE_GEM: --other-configs
```

Then run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 5):

That works for me! (Postgres 93, mac ox 10.9.1)1. download @ http://postgresapp.com/ and than

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck on my bundle install for 3 days. Tried Everything like adding **env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"** gem install pg -- **--with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/bin/pg_config**

I was able to see pg gem getting installed after this command but still it was not installing from bundle install, which was a pain because I dint know what to write in Gemfile except gem 'pg'

The thing which finally worked for me was to find that my pg_config was in **/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config** and by default the Gemfile bundle install looks in **/usr/local/bin/pg_config**

I just ran the following command and magic happened.
**bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config**

Answer (score 4):

In my case it didn't work if you don't specify the arch flags, OS X 10.10.3 and postersApp 9.4

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- \--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way for me to resolve this was to use [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) and set up my env vars so `gem install pg` just works (instead of requiring the `--with-pg-config` flag).

Using [Homebrew Cask](https://caskroom.github.io/),

```
brew cask install postgres
echo 'export PG_HOME=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$PG_HOME/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# now it just works
gem install pg
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what it worked for me:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I uninstalled the version installed via homebrew and switched to [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) (v9.3.4.2 at the time of writing).

It only seemed to work when prepending the environment architecture flags and specifying the path to `pg_config`. Your milage might vary, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20226895/341929) could help with variations on `pg_config`'s location.

Here is the final, complete command that worked for me:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- \
--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 2):

sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config

Comment: this also worked for me with bundle install like so: `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

I had installed postgres using homebrew on mac. Used below command to find the location

```
which postgres
/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/postgres
```

Installed gem using below command. In the above path just replace the postgres with pg_config since command requires path for pg_config.

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when running bundle install regarding the pg gem (using Mac OS X Mavericks).  After hours of researching, I found the solution.  I installed postgres using homebrew

```
brew install postgres
```

After installing that, I created a new rails app using postgres.  I ran

```
bundle install
```

to no avail (got same error as the question). I used

```
which psql
```

to figure out where my postgres was installed, it returned

```
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

before running bundle install again, I had to change the global path to build.pg by running the following

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
```

then I ran bundle install again and voila!  I used the postgres where brew installed it.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on 10.9.3 with Xcode 5.1.1 was the following:

```
brew update
brew install postgresql 
gem install pg -v '0.17.1'
```

I needed pg 0.17.1

Answer (score 1):

On OS X Mavericks with latest Postgres App do the following with sudo privileges

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v '0.17.1' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the error message looked like this:

`Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions`

`Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`...`

`checking for pg_config... no`

`No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config`

As the error message shows, it's trying to execute the command/script "pg_config". So just add it to the path from wherever your Postgres installation is. In my case, I did:

`export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin:$PATH`

then

`bundle`

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

For any lost soul outthere still having this issue with no resolution and have a `brew` installed **ruby** and **postgres**. Here's the following steps to make sure of:

- Make sure your version of `ruby` wasn't installed with the `--universal` flag.

  - This was the hardest thing to figure out, I had `--universal` which was the final root of the problem.
- Make sure you have initialized `postgresql` properly with `initdb` and `createdb` commands (look elsewhere for steps to do this).
- Make sure `Xcode` (Optional) and `command line tools` is installed; on the terminal:

  - `xcode-select --install`
  - `sudo xcodebuild -license` (if Xcode installed) or open the application and accept the license agreement.
  - Reboot Computer
- `which ruby`, `which gem` and `which postgres` should show `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, `/usr/local/bin/gem` and `/usr/local/bin/postgres` respectfully.
- On the terminal run:

  - `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config`
  - **or**
  - `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config`
- Making sure all these steps are satisfied I was able to solve the following errors:

  - `ruby.h` header error
  - `developer tools installed first` error

Answer (score 1):

First of all find pg_config location

```
sudo find / -name "pg_config" -print
```

The answer is /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config in my configuration (MAC Maverick)

Then try installing something like below

gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config

if this does not work then try to check in what way you installed postgresql

brew/mac port/setup

then you have to try relevant option to the same.

Thank you.

Ram

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, this was the solution I've found.

If you run `brew doctor`, it will tell you that probably you have installed something without brew that have changed the permissions on some folders, and so, you need to change permissions back to you on that folder.

Inside `/usr/local/share/man`, what you can do is the following:

`sudo chown [yourusername] man7`

And then:

`brew link postgres`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, after installing Mavericks 'bundle update' was throwing an error on the pg gem, which is only used on production and not locally.

I use Brew to manage my packages and postgresql was already installed, but still I was getting the 'no pg_config' error.

The fix was to just 'brew uninstall postgresql', then 'brew install postgresql'. After which I was immediately able to successfully run 'bundle update'

Answer (score 0):

Postgres 9.4:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice, to avoid this being lost in the flood of the 19 other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su
```

then

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v '0.18'
```

worked on 10.10.2

Answer (score 0):

If after trying everything here it still won't install, try opening Xcode and accepting the license agreement.