# Can't run cloned repository

Tags: github, ruby-on-rails-4, repository, clone, bundle-install

How do I download my old code from github? I made a mistake on my app, and when I try to download the old zip file from github and run it I get an error.

I think I'm doing it right, don't I just need to clone the repository? When I do, i get this error when I try to run the server:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

and when I run bundel install I still get the error.

I also get this error:

```
bundle install doesn't work and I still get the error along with this one:Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed Mavericks, that is the source of your problem. I had to install another gem with native dependencies that needed to be compiled after I installed Mavericks, and some changes as to which compiler Mavericks uses to compile gem dependencies creates problems. In your case, I would suggest you pick one of the solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625487/impossible-to-install-pg-gem-on-my-mac-with-mavericks) to resolve your PG installation problems.

Answer (score 1):

It ssems to me that you do not have install Postgres. Install it and try `bundle install` again.
How install Postgres on Ubuntu (of course you can have another system :) ) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: I have a mac, and I read somewhere that PostgreSQL comes automatically on macs, is that not true?

Comment: I really don't know. You can try to use some console commands connected with postgres (I believe that they are the same): `psql -U postgres` or `which postgres`. If system does not know about about PG than you will see appropriate errors