# Pg gem on Mavericks : NameError: uninitialized constant PG

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems, osx-mavericks, pg

I followed this thread ([Cannot install pg gem in Mavericks with Postgres.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224483/cannot-install-pg-gem-in-mavericks-with-postgres-app)) to get the 'pg' gem successfully working with Postgres.app on Mavericks.

Here is the output of gem list:

```
mythlabs:~ myth$ gem list pg

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

pg (0.17.1)
mythlabs:~ myth$
```

However, now that I have the gem installed, in irb :

```
mythlabs:~ myth$ irb
1.9.3-p0 :001 > require 'pg'  => true 
1.9.3-p0 :002 > conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'myth' ) NameError: uninitialized constant PG    from (irb):2    from /Users/myth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p0 :003 >
```

How can I go around fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem was using that version of the gem, where you were suppose to use `PGConn.open('` instead of `PG.connect(`, which was my issue.