# PG gem on OSX Yosemite not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, osx-yosemite, pg

Ruby Version 2.0.0p481

Rails Version 4.1.8

PG Version 0.18.1

I am trying to follow Heroku's [Getting Started with Heroku Tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby). Everything has worked fine until I need to run the app locally and migrate the database. The command `bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate` gives me the error:

```
Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.1.8) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I run `bundle install`:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.2
Using minitest 5.5.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.8
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.8
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.1.8
Using mime-types 2.4.3
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.1.8
Using activemodel 4.1.8
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.8
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.0
Using execjs 2.3.0
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.8
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using jbuilder 2.2.6
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--enable-windows-cross
--disable-windows-cross
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
--with-pqlib
--without-pqlib
--with-libpqlib
--without-libpqlib
--with-ms/libpqlib
--without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/avl1/Desktop/btc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/avl1/Desktop/btc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'`:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

When I run `sudo gem install pg -v '0.18.1'`

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--enable-windows-cross
--disable-windows-cross
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
--with-pqlib
--without-pqlib
--with-libpqlib
--without-libpqlib
--with-ms/libpqlib
--without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

I have tried everything I can find involving the pg gem on google. I have no idea what's wrong. Any help is MUCH appreciated! I am running the Postgresql App and I've built apps using the PG gem on this machine before, just not since upgrading to Yosemite.

@maxshelley - I did that and it said I didn't have permissions. Used `sudo` with it and it gave me this error:
    Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config'
    This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--enable-windows-cross
--disable-windows-cross
--with-pg-config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
--with-pqlib
--without-pqlib
--with-libpqlib
--without-libpqlib
--with-ms/libpqlib
--without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

@maxshelley - Here's my mkmf.log file.

```
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- yes

"xcrun clang -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS  -arch x86_64 -arch i386  -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... -------------------- yes

"xcrun clang -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS  -arch x86_64 -arch i386  -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq/libpq-fs.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for pg_config_manual.h... -------------------- yes

"xcrun clang -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS  -arch x86_64 -arch i386  -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <pg_config_manual.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -------------------- no

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib/libpq.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib/libpq.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_PQconnectdb", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-ddf793.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:7:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include/libpq-fe.h:250:1: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... -------------------- no

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -llibpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: library not found for -llibpq
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -llibpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:7:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include/libpq-fe.h:250:1: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... -------------------- no

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -lms/libpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: library not found for -lms/libpq
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -lms/libpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:7:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/include/libpq-fe.h:250:1: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's pulling the `pg_config` values from `/usr/local/bin/pg_config` however I've had better experience with the Postgres app when telling it to use it's own `pg_config` value.

You can do this with the `with-pg-config` flag:

```
gem install pg -v '0.18.1' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

You need to find the correct path for your machine. Go to your Applications folder, right-click on Postgres.app and select 'Show Package Contents' and you can find the pg_config file in there.

**Update:**

Some very kind individual has been keeping an up-to-date list of pg_config paths at [Cannot install pg gem in Mavericks with Postgres.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224483/cannot-install-pg-gem-in-mavericks-with-postgres-app)

Comment: I tried that and it gave more errors. I appended the results to the original question

Comment: What does the mkmf.log file say? This answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq - indicates that adding the `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` flag could resolve the issue?

Comment: I added my mkmf.log file to the post. Also, when I install with the `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` flag, it successfully installs but as soon as I go back to the original command (`bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate`) it tells me I don't have rails 4.1.8 installed and says to run `bundle install` which takes me back to the beginning issue with pg not being able to install. I tried re-installing the rails gem before dealing with the pg gem and it successfully installed, then successfully installed pg but when I run that first command again it says rails isn't installed.

Comment: Does the same thing occur if you use `bin/rake db:create` - try running those two commands (create and migrate) as two separate commands.

Comment: Another thought: are you using RVM? Are you on the same version of Ruby and using the same gemset every time? If you'd installed the gems and then moved to another project that altered your RVM settings they may no longer be available when you come back to this project?

Comment: When I run `bin/rake db:create` I get the error `You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run 'gem pristine --all' for better startup performance. Could not find pg-0.18.1 in any of the sources. Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.`

Comment: I am using rvm. I am on the same version of ruby with the same gemset and haven't switched back and forth on projects since I attempted to start this one.