# Impossible to install postgres gem on my mac with OS X/Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql

I've seen this question posted dozens of times across a bunch of different sites, with lots of different answers--none of which seems to work.

I'm trying to install the 'pg' gem on my Mac (OS X/Yosemite), but keep getting the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib
```

I've already tried reinstalling Postgres with `$ brew install postgresql`, using `sudo gem install pg`, and upgrading xcode using `xcode-select --install`.

Any insight on what this means would be very helpful.

Comment: does my answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12273968/981616

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224483/cannot-install-pg-gem-in-mavericks-with-postgres-app.

Comment: Thanks, guys, neither of these solutions works. I've been on here reading for about five hours now.

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq

Comment: Might have to add the directory containing libpq to your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`