# Failure to build native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I am new to rails and attempting to switch my default DB to Postgres from SQLite3. I have encountered an error. I am using gem install pg and getting this error error: Error installing pg: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. I am using Mavericks OSX and Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.12, and PG 9.3 –The goal is to deploy a sample app to heroku (which doesnt seem to support SQLite.

Steps I have tried:

link 1: [Installing PG gem on OS X - failure to build native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-failure-to-build-native-extension)

link 2(heroku instructions): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

EDITED TO INCLUDE SPECIFIC ERROR MESSAGE BELOW:

```
HEAD https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
HEAD https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/.gemtest
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/BSDL
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ChangeLog
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/Contributors.rdoc
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/History.rdoc
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/LICENSE
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/Manifest.txt
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/POSTGRES
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/README-OS_X.rdoc
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/README-Windows.rdoc
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/README.ja.rdoc
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/README.rdoc
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/Rakefile
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/Rakefile.cross
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/errorcodes.def
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/errorcodes.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/errorcodes.txt
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/extconf.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/gvl_wrappers.c
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/gvl_wrappers.h
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/pg.c
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/pg.h
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/pg_connection.c
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/pg_errors.c
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/pg_result.c
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/vc/pg.sln
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/vc/pg_18/pg.vcproj
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/vc/pg_19/pg_19.vcproj
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg/connection.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg/constants.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg/exceptions.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg/result.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/array_insert.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/async_api.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/async_copyto.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/async_mixed.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/check_conn.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/copyfrom.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/copyto.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/cursor.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/disk_usage_report.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/issue-119.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/losample.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/minimal-testcase.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/notify_wait.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/pg_statistics.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/replication_monitor.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/test_binary_values.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/wal_shipper.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/sample/warehouse_partitions.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/spec/data/expected_trace.out
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/spec/data/random_binary_data
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/spec/lib/helpers.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/spec/pg/connection_spec.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/spec/pg/result_spec.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.0/spec/pg_spec.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from extconf.rb:39:in `<main>'
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing? What error are you seeing? What platform (OS, Ruby version) are you using?

Comment: I am using gem install pg and getting this error error: Error installing pg: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. I am using Mavericks OSX and Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.12, and PG 9.3

Comment: Have you installed XCode from Apple so that you have a native compiler?

Comment: attach some error information would help.

Comment: Yes I have Xcode. I had this problem in the past with another gem removed it from the gemfile to avoid the issue, but now I need Postgres , so can't simply remove it from the gem file.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to build the gem `pg`, which has C or C++ code in it, and the compilation phase is not working.  Under OS X, you must install [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) or get a compiler by other means, and the shell you're using to run `bundle install` must have the compiler in its path.  I've compiled `pg` many times under OS X, though I have not upgraded to Mavericks.

If you have XCode installed, the above paragraph doesn't apply.  You'll get additional information on what's going wrong if you try `gem install pg`.  Try that and post the results.

The key is "You have to install development tools first."  This is a strong hint that you don't have a proper compiler.  [This page](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) says XCode must be v5.01 or later.

Comment: I have XCode installed, and pg installed as well, but gem install pg doesnt work for whatever reason even though I have XCode

Comment: Did you check the version?  Must be 5.01 for Mavericks.  The other possibility is that the path to XCode's bin has been lost in the shell you're using.  Try `gcc --version` from the shell.

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: Does the above provide any more info?

Comment: Two things to try. Start the XCode GUI and verify you have v5.01 or better.  Also try running `sudo gem install --verbose pg` to ensure permissions are not a problem and that you're getting full errors.  Need those errors including the ones coming from the compiler itself.

Comment: I confirmed I have XCode 5.02, and have edited my original post to include the output from the command you suggested above

Comment: Check this out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625487/impossible-to-install-pg-gem-on-my-mac-with-mavericks Looks like a mavericks-specific bug.

Comment: Thanks Gene, I tried to follow the instructions in that link, but no luck. One thing I noticed is that other users' pg_config files seem to be in their application folders. My PG app is in my applications folder but my config file is in the /usr/local/bin folder. Could this be part of the issue?

Comment: Resolved, installing brew install apple-gcc42 solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your help. The specific issue was resolved by me running the below command in terminal

```
brew install apple-gcc42
```

To clarify, I had the most recent XCode (with command line) and Mavericks, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.12, and PG 9.3. I am unsure why that specific command worked when I already had the command line tools installed. The one change of the output of

```
gcc--version
```

was that `--prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr`

changes to

```
--prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
```

Again, this change worked in practice, but I am not sure why this fixed things.

Comment: Some time a couple of years ago Apple dropped `gcc` from its Xcode distribution and aliased `gcc` to their own `LLVM` and `clang`-based compiler.  It's possible this broke `pg` and it still hasn't caught up.