# Error installing Postgres gem on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, rubygems

Here's the error I get when I run `gem install pg`:

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151004-5579-1t2l557.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

If I run `brew install postgres` I get:

```
Warning: postgresql-9.4.4 already installed
```

Likewise, `gem list` shows `pg (0.18.3)` and a simple `gem -v pg` gives:

```
2.4.4
```

Running `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg` returns:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.18.3
invalid options: -f fivefish
(invalid options are ignored)
Parsing documentation for pg-0.18.3
Done installing documentation for pg after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But `bundle install` throws up this error:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm seeing this in `mkmf.log`, which I think could be the biggest clue:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/postgresql93/libpq.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/lib/postgresql93/libpq.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_PQconnectdb", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-fc6c12.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Which is strange given `file /opt/local/lib/postgresql93/libpq.dylib` returns x86_64, not i386:

```
/opt/local/lib/postgresql93/libpq.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

This didn't work either:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

Comment: See if anything here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625487/impossible-to-install-pg-gem-on-my-mac-with-mavericks

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated my question to include the outcomes of those solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're almost there, because `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg` works. Try setting `ARCHFLAGS` globally, so `bundle` also can see it:

```
$ export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
$ bundle
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Afraid it didn't work for me, though.

Comment: This is the correct answer, in the general case, and resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working through this issue since yesterday.  I ended up uninstalling Postgres, homebrew, and starting from scratch.    When trying to add the 'pg' gem to my Ruby on Rail project it kept failing.  Digging through the output I kept seeing it try to link the i386 libraries.  So I tried adding the flag:

```
--arch-flags='x86_64'
```

That didn't seem to have any impact.

Then I found one where it was set right after the 'sudo'.  That seemed to do the trick.

THIS WORKED!!!!!!!!

> sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v '0.18.3' -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config --arch-flags='x86_64'

In the project I actually had to repeat the steps for some reason in the project directory.  Then re-repeat them and upgrade to version 0.18.4.

After that I could run 'bundle' and everything was included correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of the answers here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625487/impossible-to-install-pg-gem-on-my-mac-with-mavericks
```

suggest specifying the postgresql configuration file when performing the gem install. It is older but might provide the way forward. Search for *"Check you have pg_config in the installed brew"*, which explains how to find the correct filename.