# Unable to install pg gem on MAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, pg

I have been trying to install pg gem using, `gem install pg`, and its showing me an error.

Then I tried `brew install postgresql`, which, in the end showed error stating use/local/bin already exixts. If I am directly running `bundle install` in the app folder, its showing the error on installing pg 0.18.4, stating permission denied @ rb_sysopen.

The errors that I am getting:

```
Amans-MacBook-Air:~ aman$ gem install pg
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/aman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/.gemtest

Amans-MacBook-Air:~ aman$ brew install postgresql
Warning: postgresql-9.5.3 already installed, it's just not linked

Amans-MacBook-Air:~ aman$ brew link postgresql
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3... Error: File exists - /usr/local/lib
```

What should I do, any suggestions!

Comment: did you install ruby using rvm ?

Comment: No, i installed via homebrew..

Comment: Have you installed ruby or gems with `sudo` (as the superuser)?

Comment: Nopes, i simply installed being in my user directory, without using any admin commands.

Comment: it helps  you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625487/impossible-to-install-pg-gem-on-my-mac-with-mavericks)