# sudo gem install pg -v '0.18.4' does not work on macos sierra high (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, rubygems, bundle

I have difficulty trying to gem install pg -v '0.18.4' that is needed for my ruby on rails "bundle install" app which was developed about 3 years back.

> sudo gem install pg -v '0.18.4'

it complaints below:

```
conftest.c:15:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
extern void PQconnectdb();
```

full execution error https://gist.github.com/axilaris/f521685f4e5c7a8e5653bf672af1efa7

mkmf.log - https://gist.github.com/axilaris/2e4cf2729b34d751c1ce76b046a0b21c

My environment is as below:

```
Postgres 9.4.0.1
MacOs Sierra High 10.13.1

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]

$ rails -v
Rails 5.1.4
```

I tried to install 
brew install libpqxx
it doesnt work

Here are some related stackoverflow:

[Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)

[Impossible to Install PG gem on my mac with Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625487/impossible-to-install-pg-gem-on-my-mac-with-mavericks)

I want to make sure I install - sudo gem install pg -v '0.18.4'. Since on production it should be running that as well. I dont want to break anything that is running in the production ubuntu server. Currently for this question, I am setting up the environment on my mac for development to try to make a code fix.

FYI, I'ved tried on 2 macs. one original development mac which upgraded to sierra high, another is a new formatted mac with newly installed sierra high.

Comment: Please let me know the result of `brew install postgresql`. and If you don't have homebrew do this `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Comment: its already installed, so it complaints 
 this https://gist.github.com/axilaris/daa8c7831870ed4f41e20e5ecefef7da. Im a bit afraid of uninstalling it, since i have my development environment, will it remove existing db

Comment: Open `gemfile.lock` and search pg and let us know the gem version of pg.

Comment: this is the gemfile.lock https://gist.github.com/axilaris/163e4a68360acd33438a545fbaab6029.   pg (0.18.4)

Comment: Please try this `sudo gem install pg -v '0.18.4' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10.1/bin/pg_config`

Comment: thanks for helping out, but still the same problem. execution error -
 https://gist.github.com/axilaris/486b3708396d2e54a3f278550d7ac6a0 mkmf.log -
 https://gist.github.com/axilaris/40a3e9f4b652cae711e409b529713260

Comment: You are welcome. path of pg_config is wrong. find the pg_config path using this command `find /Applications -name pg_config`. and add that path in `with-pg-config=`.

Comment: its the same error. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/5e16e1b569642f6fde9c885a6694a649. maybe it maybe wise to reinstall this ? https://postgresapp.com/. generally i have been using postgres app for my development mac postgress db.this db is still working, my django is using it without problems and my previous ror until now.

Comment: it doesnt work even if i install latest postgresapp.com, even on a clean mac machine, for some reason PQconnectdb does not exist in any of -lpq, -llibpq, -lms/libpq

Comment: Try this `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v '0.18.4'`

Comment: i did try that but failed, even with - env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v '0.18.4'

Comment: where does -lpq, -llibpq, -lms/libpq comes from ?

Comment: we have to install those packages. what is error in `brew install libpqxx`?

Comment: there is no error installing libpqxx. sudo gem install pg still complains the same error. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/d493d3b109b470752fcffbc2b338e92c

Comment: just to verify, im using x86_64 architecture. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/4eb73d9096e639eaff773611cc7f7a1e

Comment: this worked!  ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install. now there is "Can't install RMagick 2.15.4" issue. anyway this is solved. tqvm for your support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

`ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install`

For RMagick do this

```
brew install imagemagick@6
brew link --force imagemagick@6
```

Please let me know if any error occur in while installing rmagick.

Comment: it didnt work with rmagick after using your commands for imagemagick@6 https://gist.github.com/axilaris/59a602402149a12b97d6e3b018d9ea03

Comment: @Axil: Try this `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick`

Comment: this was the reason. brew link --force imagemagick@6 needed to be executed again. thank you. bundle install now completes!

Comment: Can you change the answer to this >>> ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install.

Comment: ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install

Worked for mac os X